# dektrium-rbac / Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Почему после установки dektrium-rbac я не могу зайти на страницу xxx.ru/rbac?
Я получаю 403 ошибку все время

```
        'rbac' => [
           'class' => 'dektrium\rbac\Module',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, Вы не создали соответствующих разрешений для пользователя, под которым заходите на xxx.ru/rbac.